# Import-SPWeb : The DateTime represented by the string is out of range?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am trying to import an exported sub site which exists in a separate site collection to another site collection that is hosted by different web application.

I'm running the import command like this:

```
Import-SPWeb http://sitename/destweb -Path ("D:\sourceweb.cmp") –NoLogFile
```

Then I get an error message:

> Import-SPWeb : The DateTime represented by the string is out of
>   rangeImport-SPWeb

In log file, I found it throws an exception at importing a particular document library:

> [3/3/2016 10:21:22 AM] [Folder] [مجلد] Progress: Importing [3/3/2016
>   10:21:22 AM] [Folder] [مجلد]   Verbose: Source URL: DocLib/Forms/مجلد
>   [3/3/2016 10:21:22 AM] [Folder] [Docs] Progress: Importing [3/3/2016
>   10:21:22 AM] [Folder] [Docs]   Verbose: Source URL: Docs [3/3/2016
>   10:21:22 AM] [Folder] [Docs]   Error: The DateTime represented by the
>   string is out of range.
>   [3/3/2016 10:21:22 AM] [Folder] [Docs]   Debug:    at
>   System.DateTime.Parse(String s, IFormatProvider provider)    at
>   System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo.GetDateTime(String
>   name)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.MetaInfoProperty..ctor(SerializationInfoHelper
>   infoHelper)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.DictionarySerializer.SetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.FolderSerializer.SetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.XmlFormatter.CallSetObjectData(Object
>   obj, SerializationInfo objectData, ISerializationSurrogate surrogate,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector) [3/3/2016 10:21:22 AM] FatalError: The
>   DateTime represented by the string is out of range.

Note: I have the exported sub site as 3 files:

1- sourceweb.cmp

2- sourceweb1.cmp

3- sourceweb2.cmp

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is it within the same farm? Do the site collection/subsite have different regional settings?

Comment: Yes it is within the same farm, regional settings are identical, I check the regional settings before running the import command.

Comment: Can you try to import the web to a site in the same webapplication to see if that works?

Comment: I will try, but to be more specific I generated a log file and I found this:

[3/3/2016 10:21:22 AM] [Folder] [مجلد] Progress: Importing
[3/3/2016 10:21:22 AM] [Folder] [مجلد]   Verbose: Source URL: DocLib/Forms/مجلد
[3/3/2016 10:21:22 AM] [Folder] [Docs] Progress: Importing
[3/3/2016 10:21:22 AM] [Folder] [Docs]   Verbose: Source URL: Docs
[3/3/2016 10:21:22 AM] [Folder] [Docs]   Error: The DateTime represented by the string is out of range.

Comment: Must be the something with the regional setting as the error seems to be a generic C# error when it fails to parse the date because of different date settings. Can you compare the regional setting page on your subsite and your target site to see if there is any difference at all?

Comment: Regional settings are identical, i tried importing to a sub site within the same web application, but no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36503/discussion-between-mohammad-akilan-and-christoffer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also have same problem. After couple of hours of googling I have found this link
http://codecaching.blogspot.ru/2012/11/importing-cmp-and-string-was-not.html

There was a problem with wrong year in date 29 May **60354** 05:36:10 -0000
In my case in have not found any wrong dates in my Manifest.xml files but I have found some max dates like 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59.

I think the import process parses the date(31 Dec 9999 23:59:59) and adds timezone to it and goes out of bounds.

I have replaced all 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 to 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 and problem has disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I used import-spweb and export sp web with the flag -NoFileCompression

Then it creates everything in a folder , you can then find the manifest file and remove the random dates with (notepad)  then import using the same flag and set the path to the folder , this resolved my issue a bit easier than trying to extract and convert multiple cmp / cab files.